# Reactjs Apollo Client Graphql doesn't always attach my refresh cookie in headers

Tags: reactjs, cookies, graphql, jwt, nestjs

I have a ReactJS application running locally (with https) on port 3000 and a Nest js Graphql lambda server runnning locally (http) on port 4000.

I have have used this [article](https://wanago.io/2020/09/21/api-nestjs-refresh-tokens-jwt/) as an example to implement JWT token and cookie (for refresh token) based authentication.

My issue currently is that apollo client in the react application, does not always attach the cookies to the request and that happens randomly. I can see the cookie in the browser storage.

Apollo Client & Http Link set up

```
        this.cache = new InMemoryCache()
    
       this.apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
          cache: this.cache,
          link: this.authLink.concat(this.httpLink),
          connectToDevTools: process.env.REACT_APP_STAGE === 'dev',
          credentials: "include",
        })
    
    
     private readonly httpLink = createHttpLink({
        uri: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}`,
        credentials: 'include',
        fetchOptions: {
          credentials: 'include'
        }
      })

  private readonly authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: this.accessToken ? `Bearer ${this.accessToken}` : '',
      },
    }
  })
```

Server Setup:
Graphql options passed to nest js Graphql module

```
import { GqlModuleOptions, GqlOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { join } from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class GraphqlOptions implements GqlOptionsFactory {
  createGqlOptions(): Promise<GqlModuleOptions> | GqlModuleOptions {
    if (process.env.STAGE === 'dev') {
      return {
        context: ({ req, res }) => {
          return {
            req,
            res
          }
        },
        autoSchemaFile: 'src/schema.graphql',
        playground: {
          endpoint: '/graphql',
        },
        engine: {
          reportSchema: true,
        },
        cors: {
          credentials: true,
          origin: ["https://localhost:3000"],
        }
      }
      
    } else {
      return {
        context: ({ req, res }) => ({ req, res }),
        autoSchemaFile: '/tmp/schema.graphql',
        playground: {
          endpoint: '/graphql',
        },
        introspection: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When a client requests a token for the first time i provide it in the response header using the bellow code in a mutation resolver:

```
context["res"].setHeader('Set-Cookie', [refreshToken.cookie])
```